# only one program reporting OpenGL problem

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, kernel, graphics, opengl

ubuntu 14.04 with nvidia has just upgraded kernel to 3.16.0-52-generic. after that i tried to run tremulous (with tremfusion) and i got:

```
GLimp_Init() - could not load OpenGL subsystem
```

all other 3D games (xonotic, open arena, red eclipse) are working without any problem.`glxgears` works, also `glxinfo | grep direct` shows

```
direct rendering: Yes
    GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_EXT_direct_state_access, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, 
    GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_indirect, 
    GL_EXT_direct_state_access, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced,
```

also before the upgrade there was no problem with tremulos. any ideas why only one program reports the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer. problem had nothing to do with OpenGL. some automatically downloaded maps were malformed. after removing them game works again